# Angularjs not minified reference errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am including "not" minified libraries like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/angularjs/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/angularjs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and I am getting these errors:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated comment [angular.js:10174]
TypeError: angular is undefined [angular-resource.js:8]
TypeError: angular is undefined [angular-route.js:22]
ReferenceError: angular is not defined [app.js]
```

However, when I include the minified version instead of "not" minified version of angular.js, I get the error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

with this code in app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(myAppRouteProvider);

function myAppRouteProvider($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/login/login.html'})
        .when('/login', {template: '<h3>Login</h3>'});
}
```

Am I missing any libraries or the code is invalid?

Comment: more than just minification done in `.min`... there is more verbose error output in development version

Comment: Am I doing anything different?

Comment: create demo that replicates problem in plunker

Comment: Try using the cdn version of angular so you can be sure you have a good copy of Angular (I've seen issues with bad copies before): https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js

Comment: Just tried your suggested link Kayak, but I am getting the same errors.